# NuPack (NuGet) on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, nuget

Can NuPack (NuGet) be installed on Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could KIND OF get things working with Nuget.exe from the command line via some macros and custom toolbars, the add the references yourself.

Comment: Scott, I'm assuming you didn't give these folks the permission to copy your article onto their site: http://www.geekofwar.com/article/9679/NuGet-Support-for-Visual-Studio-2008 ?  Dana linked to this in her (hopefully deleted by now) spam answer.

Comment: An updated link for Scott's article: [http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetSupportForVisualStudio2008.aspx](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetSupportForVisualStudio2008.aspx)

Answer (score 30):

No...It supports only VS 2010

From [NuPack FAQ](http://nupack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Frequently%20Asked%20Questions)

> The NuPack Package Manager Console
>   requires that PowerShell 2.0 be
>   installed, thus NuPack requires one of
>   the following operating systems:
>
> ```
> * Windows Vista
> * Windows 7
> * Windows Server 2008
> ```
>
> NuPack also supports:
>
> ```
> * Visual Studio 2010
> * Visual Web Developer 2010 (this support is planned, but not yet
> implemented.)
> ```

Answer (score 5):

There is [NuGet Support in SharpDevelop 4.1](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/01/23/NuGetSupportInSharpDevelop.aspx), which in turn supports Visual Studio 2008 solutions.

Comment: Sharpdevelp 4.1 is in alpha now. However, that does present an awkward but potentially viable solution.

Comment: Switching to SharpDevelop is not realy a solution to the problem, but thanks for the information

Comment: You can install SharpDevelop in parallel with Visual Studio, and use it to update packages. SharpDevelop reads and writes the same solution and project files as Visual Studio does. In short: you can use SharpDevelop as your package manager.